# AmChart legend in one line

Tags: legend, amcharts, legend-properties

I'm trying to get AmChart chart legends into one line, but without luck. Legends are separated (one for line).

[image]

Actual settings for from documentation http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmLegend is
following.

```
 "legend": {
                    "equalWidths": false,
                    //"periodValueText": "total: [[value.sum]]",
                    "position": "bottom",
                    "valueAlign": "left",
                    "labelWidth": 100,
                    "valueWidth": 200,
                    //"width": 100,
                    "align": "center"

                },
```

I Would like to ask how to get all chart legends into one line?

Many Thanks for any advice.

Comment: labelWidth 100 + valueWidth 200 makes one legend entry 300px width. And as your container is not very wide, entries are wrapped to fit. try to reduce these numbers or do not set them at all.

Answer (score 6):

you can try legend{
"maxColumns": 1,
}

Comment: Actually @Amal is right {"[maxColumns](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmLegend#maxColumns)" :1,} is the correct approach for this

Answer (score 1):

I think it auto resize follows width of div.
Btw, You can change "valueWidth" lower.

Answer (score 1):

Try reducing "labelWidth" and "valueWidth" to fit just the content

Comment: How to find out the content's value for the labelWidth and valueWidth?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `equalWidths = false` and `valueWidth = 0`, like this:

```js
"legend": {
  "equalWidths": false,
  "valueWidth": 0
}
```